# Spring MVC 3 hibernate save with ManyToMany causing duplicates to be created

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a hibernate User that has a ManyToMany relationship with a role, and a ManyToMany relationship with a site.

My drop downs are correct, I get the list of roles.  However, when I submit my form and save the User that is submitted, it does not store a reference to the Role objects.  It takes the submitted id from the select for the selected role and creates a new Role object with the ID as the roleName and generates another id and makes a new role with a guid for the ID and a guid for the roleName.  The roleName guid being the value of the select in the form.  Any idea what the hell is going on here?

Here is the relevant code, minus imports and getters/setters:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "glog_role")
public class Role extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
  @Transient
  private Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Role.class);

  @Transient
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 839358406019511981L;

  @Column(unique=true)
  @NotNull
  String roleName;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    Collection<User> users;

  public Role(String name){
    super();
    this.roleName = name;
  }

  public Role(){
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
  }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Role other = (Role) obj;
        if (roleName == null) {
            if (other.roleName != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!roleName.equals(other.roleName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result
                + ((roleName == null) ? 0 : roleName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

This is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "glog_user")
public class User extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
  @Transient
  private Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);

  @Transient
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 838487206019511981L;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
  String userName;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  Boolean active = true;

  @Column
  @Size(max = 255)
  String password;

  @Column
  @Size(min = 7, max = 7)
  String hexColor = "#FFFFFF";

    @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "glog_users_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
             )
             @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private Collection<Role> roles;

  /**
   * , inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "glog_site_id", nullable =
   * false, updatable = false) })
   */
    @JsonManagedReference
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "glog_users_sites", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "site_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
             )
             @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
             Collection<Site> sites;

  public User() {
    super();
    sites = new ArrayList<Site>();
  }
```

Here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userSiteForm(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute User u,
        BindingResult br, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("errors", br.getAllErrors());
        setModelAttributes("user", model);
        return modelForm(model, "user");
    }
    L.info("User is: {}", u);
    glogService.saveOrUpdate(User.class, u);

    model.addAttribute("message", "Entry Log");
    model.addAttribute("user", u);
    ra.addFlashAttribute(FLASH_MESSAGE, "User saved successfully");
    return "redirect:/app/admin/user/form";
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="${form_model_attrib}" method="POST" action='${form_save }'>
  <h2><spring:message code="user_form.header"/></h2>

  <form:label path="userName">
    <spring:message code="user.userName" />
  </form:label>
  <form:input path="userName" autofocus='true' />

  <form:label path="hexColor">
    <spring:message code="user.hexColor"/>
  </form:label>
    <form:input path="hexColor" type="color"/>

  <form:label path="sites">
    <spring:message code="user.sites"/>
  </form:label>
  <form:select path="sites" items="${sites }" itemLabel="siteName" itemValue="id">
  </form:select>

  <form:label path="roles">
    <spring:message code="user.roles"/>
  </form:label>
  <form:select path="roles" items="${roles }" itemLabel="roleName" itemValue="id">
  </form:select>

  <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code='form.submit'/>" />
  <%-- <a href='javascript:;' onclick='submitForm("${save_url}");'>Ajax post</a> --%>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was really annoying, but the solution is to only have a no-argument constructor for the Role.  If not, the constructor was called, and since the ID is a string too that's what screwed me up.

I suppose you can either have only a no-arg constructor (what I did) or tell Spring which one is preferred.

Edit:
The other thing you have to do is register a converter that looks up the id passed from the form from the DAO:

```
@Override
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Server.class, "serverId", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) {
            Server type = (Server) em.createNamedQuery("Server.findById")
                .setParameter("id", Short.parseShort(text)).getSingleResult();
            setValue(type);
        }
    });
}
```